# How to sync two methods to prevent them both being accessed by different threads simultaneously but allow as many instances of only one method

Tags: java

How to sync two methods to prevent them both being accessed by different threads simultaneously but allow as many instances of only one method?

So for example, if I created a class for traffic lights and a class for cars. I want a `trafficlights.goleft();` and `trafficlights.goright();`.

How do I make it so that many threads of car can run goleft at the same time but right is locked.

Currently I have added the synchronized keyword in front of the methods but this fully locks them.

```
public class Trafficlights{

    public synchronized static void crossEast(int num) throws InterruptedException {
       System.out.println("Car crossing Eastwards");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Car is now across");
    }

    public synchronized static void crossWest(int num) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Car crossing westwards");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Car is now across");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i =1; i < 20; i++) {
            Car car = new Car(i);
            car.run();
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: Hi, you may have to provide code of what you have tried so far, so that people can see how wjat you are doing and answer your question. Thanks

Comment: The light status should be read-only to cars.  Why is threading a factor here?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The traffic light idea isn't relevant it's just to understand how to lock one method whilst allowing another to be used by many threads.

Comment: Oh, I see.  It's an exercise.

Comment: OK, I think what you need is an `intersectionIsClear` method, or somesuch.

Comment: I think this can be solved by designing it in a different way.

Comment: "how to lock one method whilst allowing another to be used by many threads" -> Who decides which method is to be locked. It is the place where you synchronize

Comment: @Ben Has the solution I provided worked? What did you do to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Using synchronized keyword for a non static method synchronizes over the object instance on which methods are getting called. So if you have other such methods they would be locked like you described. The key to this concept is to know what is the lock/semaphore.

If you don't want just a subset of methods to be synchronized over their operation you will have to create a lock yourself and only those subset of methods should synchronize over this lock.

In java, if I remember the syntax you put your method body within synchronized block:

```
goLeft() {
    synchronized (leftRightLock) { 
        // Your goLeft code here
    }
}
```

Any object can be a lock but enums used to be preferred because of their early creational properties. But in your case being at the instance level create something in the constructor and you are good.

Disclaimer: I am no longer coding in Java since many years pre 1.7 so take the syntax with a grain of salt. I am hoping there are other better ways to accomplish this but the core concept remains be it Java or other languages.

Comment: Lock is called object's monitor I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I reworked my previous answer, because it was not a good example.

The previous solution was supposed to be a guide, so you could work on your own implementation. Instead of helping you, this might have confused you, so I made a different example of something that could solve your problem.

Note that I have TESTED this solution and it works.

```
//Constants that represent left and right
private static final int LEFT = 1;
private static final int RIGHT = 2;

//permits set to 0 initially. No car is allowed to cross, either left or right
private static Semaphore goLeft = new Semaphore(0, true);
private static Semaphore goRight = new Semaphore(0, true);

//booleans to indicate whether cars will go left or right
public static boolean leftGreen = false, rightGreen = false;

public static void crossEast() throws InterruptedException {
    goRight.acquire();
    System.out.println("Car crossing Eastwards");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("Car is now across");
    goRight.release();
}

public static void crossWest() throws InterruptedException {
    goLeft.acquire();
    System.out.println("Car crossing westwards");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("Car is now across");
    goLeft.release();
}

//Method to be called by user, to turn a the right or left light to green
public static void turnOnLight(int light){
    giveGreen(light);
    try{
        switchLight();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ie){
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Depending on the constant passed, leftGreen or rightGreen will be set to true
private static void giveGreen(int light){
    if(light == LEFT){
        leftGreen = true;
        rightGreen = false;
    }

    else if(light == RIGHT){
        leftGreen = false;
        rightGreen = true;
    }
    else{
        //you can throw a custom exception here
    }
}

//This method will release a permit to the light that is green (true)
private static void switchLight() throws InterruptedException {
    if(leftGreen){
        if(goRight.availablePermits() > 0)
            goRight.acquire();
        goLeft.release();
        //If thread tried to call goEast, it would be put to sleep
    }
    else if(rightGreen){
        if(goLeft.availablePermits() > 0)
            goLeft.acquire();
        goRight.release();
        //now allowed to go right
    }
}

//Of course you shouldn't have throws and catch the exception at runtime instead
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    Thread[] cars = new Thread[4];
    /*let's say we want to allow cars to only go left. If you don't
     turn on any light, the cars won't move*/
    turnOnLight(LEFT);
    for(Car car : cars) {
        car = new Thread(new Car());
        System.out.print(car.getId()+": ");
        car.run();
        car.join();
    }
}
```

I defined a simple class `Car` to demonstrate how this works. This can be changed of course.

```
public class Car implements Runnable {

    private boolean leftLight, rightLight;

    public Car(){
        this.leftLight = TrafficLights.leftGreen;
        this.rightLight = TrafficLights.rightGreen;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if(leftLight)
                TrafficLights.crossWest();
            else if(rightLight)
                TrafficLights.crossEast();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```